# How to send a REST call with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt5, qtnetwork

I have started started working with Qt framework and after reading the documentation for Qt5 and some examples across some blogs, I wrote the following program but I does not seem to do the correct job.

I am writing a class for which I need to write a method Login and logout.
For login method, I am writing following code:

```cpp
void User::login()
{
    const QUrl loginUrl = (this->m_url).append("/api/auth/login");
    QNetworkRequest loginRequest;
    loginRequest.setUrl(loginUrl);
    loginRequest.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");
    QJsonObject body;
    QJsonObject data;
    data.insert("userName", this->m_userName);
    data.insert("password", this->m_password);
    body.insert("data", data);
    body.insert("provider", "LDAP");

    //loginRequest.setBody(QJsonDocument(body).toJson());
    const QByteArray json = QJsonDocument(body).toJson();

    QNetworkReply* reply = m_manager.post(loginRequest, QJsonDocument(body).toJson());
    while (!reply->isFinished())
    {
        // wait for the request to complete
    }
    QByteArray response_data = reply->readAll();
    QJsonDocument responseJson = QJsonDocument::fromJson(response_data);
    reply->deleteLater();

    std::cout << response_data.toStdString() << std::endl;
}
```

After I call this method in my main function, If I check in fiddler, I cannot see any request made also, the program goes into infinite loop. Can you tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cause

As you say, *the program goes into infinite loop*. The very one you have created:

```
while (!reply->isFinished())
{
    // wait for the request to complete
}
```

Simply put, with `QNetworkReply* reply = m_manager.post(loginRequest, QJsonDocument(body).toJson());` you do not send a request, but merely declare your wish to do so. Right after that you block the event loop, leaving Qt no chance to fulfill your wish.

### Solution

Use signals and slots as intended. Think about team as events and callbacks. A good starting point is the description of [`QNetworkAccessManager`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#details):

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished,
        this, &MyClass::replyFinished);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution. Simple and does not change the code logic, but does not follow Qt coding recommendations:

Just change

```
while (!reply->isFinished())
{
    // wait for the request to complete
}
```

to

```
while (!reply->isFinished())
{
    qApp->processEvents();
}
```

You may need to add:

```
#include <QApplication>
```

This way you block login function in loop and give Qt chance to process your request.